# Find the strings that contain at least one of substrings from a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formulas

I am facing a problem to search a value from a range into a string. Here is my sample of data and expected results

[image: Here is my sample of data and expected results]

I am working with Google Sheets and I can use custom formula if it's 
necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with regexextract - if you only are searching for example for the "value 1" in the first set of strings in A2 you would use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,D2)
```

If your checking to see if A2 has either B2,B3,B4 then you can use:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,JOIN("|",B2:B4))
```

If a row doesnt have the value your searching for, you can remove the default #N/A by wrapping either function  in iferror.

```
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,D2))

=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,JOIN("|",B2:B4)))
```

If your process is slightly different , then please elaborate with a couple more details or share a sample spreadsheet

Comment: Hello Aurielle,
Your answer solved my problem. Thanks a lot.

May i ask a good link to learn regex ?

Comment: @anthonyf15 Off the top of my head I dont have a good link for you (i will add one if i come across a good one) - when I learned it was a combination of reading many links and lots of trial and error until It finally clicked - but I did eventually near the end start using a really great app for mac that was super nifty called regexRX - not sure if they have for both windows and mac but worth taking a look